# golang ParseQuery url gives me wrong output

Tags: go

I have the following code:

```
func init() {
    today := time.Now()

    // If ENDPOINT is empty, It'll use this hardcoded endpoint. The ENDPOINT variable should not contain any text after "ModifiedDate gt". The actual date is currentDay-1
    if ENDPOINT == "" {
        ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:8000/Contacts/Export/?$select=Firstname,Lastname,Email,SubaccountId&$filter=EEA eq '' and ModifiedDate gt"
    }

    // Append CurrentDay-1 in YYY`enter code here`Y-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ format.
    // The time is NOT in UTC. It's the local time of the machine on which lambda function was running
    ENDPOINT = fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", ENDPOINT, today.AddDate(0, 0, -1).Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05Z"))

    var err error
    // parse the url
    PARSED_ENDPOINT, err = url.Parse(ENDPOINT)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Invalid $ENDPOINT", err)
    }

    // parse the query parameters
    parsedQueryParams, err := url.ParseQuery(PARSED_ENDPOINT.RawQuery)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("error in parsing query parameters", err)
    }

    // URLEncode query parameters
    PARSED_ENDPOINT.RawQuery = parsedQueryParams.Encode()
}
```

When I output the URL, I get:

```
'http://localhost:8000/Contacts/Export/?%24filter=EEA+eq+%27%27+and+ModifiedDate+gt+2018-10-22T08%3A45%3A45Z&%24select=Email%2CFirstname%2CLastname%2CSubaccountId%2CEEA'
```

How do I return:

```
'http://localhost:8000/Contacts/Export/?$filter=EEA%20eq%20%27%27%20and%20ModifiedDate%20gt%202018-10-22T00:00:00Z&$select=Email,Firstname,Lastname,SubaccountId,EEA'
```

Any advice is much appreciated

Comment: This is because you query contains spaces which are converted in %20 when coded.

Comment: if i use postman, to test my query, it converts it correctly, and the commas are also being changed to `%2C`

Comment: yes postman is smart enough to do that. You should pass your query inside url.Query

Comment: @khinesteryou should remove dupl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946228/golang-parsequery-url-gives-me-wrong-output

Comment: yes, i already mentioned it on that post, not sure why this has happened

Comment: Just to give some little feedback: Go's standard library uses camel case over snake case or all caps const, etc. and is the recommended way to declare variables: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#mixed-caps

Additionally, you may want to be using `main()` in your code instead of `init()` as that is primarily used to ensure initial states before program execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Golang provide url package to manage this problem and pass the query string with key values to the browser and parse it accordingly after encoding the string which will resolve special characters issue:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    query := make(url.Values)
    query.Add("key", "value")
    url := &url.URL{RawQuery: query.Encode(), Host: "foo", Scheme: "http"}
    fmt.Println(url)
}
```

Avoid using string query and adding values using fmt package Sprintf methods.This is not a proper way to manage query strings and creating a dynamic url.